# The constructor Object(String) is undefined; Method setLayout is undefined for type eventHandling?

Tags: user-interface, methods

```
import java.awt.*;      
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;                 


     public class EventHandling {

private JTextField paco;
private JTextField paco2;
private JTextField paco3;
private JPasswordField passwordField;

     public EventHandling(String s, String set ) {

            super("title");                             

            setLayout(new FlowLayout());


    }

}
```

So I get this error at "super("title");" -
**The constructor Object(String) is undefined**,
and then for "setLayout(new FlowLayout());" - 
**The method setLayout(FlowLayout) is undefined for the type EventHandling**

Answer (score 0):

```
public class EventHandling extends JFrame {
```

...